# Spring: @PostConstruct is not called

Tags: java, spring

Class A:

```
package myproject.web.factory.components;

@Component
public class AppComponentFactory{
}
```

Class B

```
package myproject.web.components;
import myproject.web.factory.components.AppComponentFactory;

@Component
public class AdminTabSheet{

   @Autowired
   private AppComponentFactory appComponentFactory;

   public AdminTabSheet() {
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      // does something with appComponentFactory
   }
}
```

Configuration XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myproject.spring" />
```

WebConfig.java:

```
package myproject.spring.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "myproject.web.components"})
public class WebConfig {
```

I have followed all the rules in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html:

- Only one method can be annotated with this annotation.
- The method MUST NOT have any parameters except in the case of EJB interceptors
- The return type of the method MUST be void.
- The method MUST NOT throw a checked exception.
- The method on which PostConstruct is applied MAY be public, protected, package private or private.
- The method MUST NOT be static .

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe WebConfig.java is in the wrong package?

Answer (score 2):

If there was no typo, I believe the correct would be

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "myproject.web"})
```

since `AppComponentFactory` is in `myproject.web.factory` package.